# How do I use a select statement to select '' when field is numeric "null"

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a flat file that I'm comparing to a staging table. The flat file as a null string is ,, (comma delimited). however for numerical fields on the table `''` is coming back as `null`. I've been able to cast that as `0`, however I can't seem to find a way to cast it as `''`, it tells me that I can't cast a numeric field as a string... not sure if my syntax isn't quite right or there may be some other way.

I've tried formating etc

```
select isnull(cast(field1 as float), '') as field1 from table1
```

or kept numeric

```
select isnull(field1, '') as field1 from table 1
```

actual results where null now = 0 for the first statement and fails on the second claiming I can't use a string.... is there a non-null equivalent of an empty "string" for numerics?

Comment: Can you explain where the source data is when you "cast a numeric field as a string"? It's confusing because you stated you are working with a file, but if you are "casting" data, then it is in SQL Server. Have you loaded the file into table and now you are comparing the data in two different tables?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense `''` isn't a valid value for a number.

Comment: I'm trying to compare a flat file to a table. I'm prepping the table data with SQL hopefully, I want the output from the selected table to = '' where null. but even though it's only an output I can't seem to get SQL to send null fields as '' in a select. This is instead of having to prep the table data with excel before comparing to the flat file.

Comment: Perhaps there's a way I can select as a non-numeric field using casting, then transform the nulls to ''? I tried some variations on this but it still claims I'm using a string for a numeric field.

Comment: Figured out the answer: ISNULL(Cast(CAST(FieldName AS FLOAT) AS Varchar(30)),'')

Answer (score 2):

> is there a non-null equivalent of an empty "string" for numerics?

No. You can only set it to `Null` or `0`.

Comment: Figured out the answer: ISNULL(Cast(CAST(FieldName AS FLOAT) AS Varchar(30)),'')

Answer (score 0):

You can't store `''` as a numeric value. Be aware that if you change your `NULLs` to `0` you won' distiquish it from 'real' 0 that came from the file. If you have an issue with comparing `NULL` to `NOT NULL` you should use [IS/NOT NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) predicate.

Comment: I'm not trying to store it, I just want SQL to output it this way.

Comment: Figured out the answer: ISNULL(Cast(CAST(FieldName AS FLOAT) AS Varchar(30)),'')